# .htaccess - redirect if visitor is logged into google

Tags: google, htaccess, cookie

I need a .htaccess redirect rule that redirects visitors to a url only if the visitor is logged into google.

I was thinking of doing it by looking into cookies

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ingoing*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*GOOGLE-COOKIE.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . example.com/outgoing [R,L]
```

What sting does a Google cookie only contain if a user is logged in?

Comment: Simply "logged into Google"? Or authenticated on your site using their Google (openId/Oauth) account? On which domain are you wanting to check for cookies?

Comment: Simply logged into Google. I need to check the cookies on my domain, from which I will then redirect the user based on the service he is logged into. I just need a rule that will tell - is user logged into Google - yes/no.

Comment: There is no way to do this simply by checking cookies. (Even) Google is not able to set cross-domain cookies (ie. on your domain) and you cannot check cookies on another domain. You _might_ be able to do this via a scripted solution using a Google API, but this is in the realms of OAuth and the user is likely to be (should) prompted for authorisation. Any other method is going to be a hack.

Comment: I've found a way on how to do it with a script, have a look at my answer if you're interested. And thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by using a script that redirects the user if he is logged into G+.

[I've scavenged the script from this site](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/tools/detect-social-network-logins/)

[The explanation on how the script works can be found here.](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/detect-visitor-social-networks/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's certainly very interesting, but very "hacky" ;) That example page doesn't appear to detect anything  for me in Google Chrome, however, Opera and Firefox appear to play along.

Comment: For me it works on Chrome perfectly, tried it yesterday and everything is working so far. Only problem is that the direct link to G+ reviews does not work on mobile devices, have to do some more research for that.

Comment: It seems that the script does require 3rd party cookies to be enabled in the browser. In Google Chrome 3rd party cookies are disabled _by default_ (which is why it's not working for me).